# Parse Days in Status field from Jira Cloud for Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, jira

I am using [Jira Cloud for Sheets](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1220382/jira-cloud-for-google-sheets-official?hosting=cloud&tab=support) Adds on in order to get `Days in Status` field from Jira, it seems to have the following syntax, from this [post](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/Parse-Time-in-Status-JQL/qaq-p/1553783)

```
<STATUS_ID>_*:*_<NUMBER_OF_TIMES_ISSUE_WAS_IN_THIS_STATUS>_*:*_<SECONDS>_*|
```

Here is an example:

```
10060_*:*_1_*:*_1121033406_*|*_3_*:*_1_*:*_7409_*|*_10000_*:*_1_*:*_270003163_*|*_10088_*:*_1_*:*_2595005_*|*_10087_*:*_1_*:*_1126144_*|*_10001_*:*_1_*:*_0
```

I am trying to extract for example how many times the issue was `In QA` status and the duration on a given status. I am dealing with parsing this pattern for obtaining this information and return it using an `ARRAYFORMULA`. `Days in Status` field information will be provided only when the issue was completed (is in `Done` status), otherwise, no information will be provided. if the issue is in `Done` status, but it didn't transition for a given status, this information will not be provided in the `Days in Status` string.

I am trying to use `REGEXEXTRACT` function to match a pattern for example:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(C2, "(10060)_\*:\*_\d+_\*:\*_\d+_\*|")
```

and it returns an empty value, where I expect `10068`. I brought my attention that when I use `REGEXMATCH` function it returns `TRUE`:

```
=REGEXMATCH(C2, "(10060)_\*:\*_\d+_\*:\*_\d+_\*|")
```

so the syntax is not clear. Google refers as a reference for Regular Expression to the following [documentation](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/doc/syntax.txt). It seems to be an issue with the vertical bar `|`, per this documentation it is a special character that should be represented like this `\v`, but this doesn't work. The `REGEXMATCH` returns `FALSE`. I am trying to use some online RegEx tester, that implements Google Sheets syntax (RE2), I found [ReGo](https://regoio.herokuapp.com), that I don't know if it is a valid one.

I was trying to use `SPLIT`function like this:

```
=query(SPLIT(C2, "_*:*_"), "SELECT Col1")
```

but it seems to be a more complicated approach for getting all the values I need from `Days in Status` field string, but it separates well all the values from the previous pattern. In this case, I am getting the first Status ID. The number of columns returned by `SPLIT`will varies because it depends on the number of statuses the issues transitioned in order to get to `DONE` status.

It seems to be a complex task given all the issues I have encounter, but maybe some of you were dealing with this before and may advise about some ideas. It requires properly parsing the information and then extracting the information on specific columns using `ARRAYFORMULA` function when it applies for a given status from `Status` column.

Here is a google spreadsheet sample with the input information. I would like to populate the information for the following columns for `Times In QA` (`C` column) and `Duration in QA` (`D` column, the information is provided in seconds I would need in days but this is a minor task) for In QA status, then the same would apply for the rest of the other statuses. I added the tab `Settings` for mapping the `Status ID` to my `Status`, I would need to use a lookup function for matching the `Status` column in the `Jira Issues` tab. I would like to have a solution, without adding helper columns maybe it will require some script.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ys6oiel1aJkQR9nfxWJsmEyd7XiNkVB-omcNL0ohckY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: @player0 Try it now, I made it public, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(1/(1/QUERY(1*IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, "10087.{5}(\d+).{5}(\d+)")), 
 "select Col1,Col2/86400 label Col2/86400''"))))
```

[image]

---

...so after we do `REGEXEXTRACT` some rows (which cannot be extracted from) will output as `#N/A` error so we wrap it into `IFNA` to remove those errors. then we multiply it by `*1` to convert everything into numeric numbers (regex works & outputs always only plain text format). then we use `QUERY` to convert 2nd column into proper seconds in one go. at this point every row has some value so to get rid of zeros for rows we don't need (like row 2,3,5,8,9,etc) and keep the output numeric, we use `IFERROR(1/(1/` wrapping. and finally, we use `INDEX` or `ARRAYFORMULA` to process our array.

Comment: Thanks @player0 again. I am able to understand the `REGEXEXTRACT`part, but I am not able to understand the rest of the formula. I was trying to google if there a specific syntax for `1/Query()`, but I was not able to find any explanation. I was trying to spit every part to understand some partial results, but it is not clear to me how you build it. Would you point some hints on how you get this result? Thanks

Comment: trying @player0 to understand your formula, I found this approach which we don't need to deal with #N/A. `Days in Status` will have information only if `Status` is Done, so this works too: `=Arrayformula(if(B2:B="Done",Query(1*REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, "_\*\|\*_10087.{5}(\d+).{5}(\d+)"), "select Col1, Col2/86400 label Col2/86400''"),))`. I added more specific information before `10087` because on my real example I found it finds the same value but on SECOND's portion of the pattern.

Comment: I realized @player0 your solution works better because it provides an empty result when the status is not present. For example the status ID: 10036 is not always present. Using the formula from my previous comment will return zero instead.